# Tag rename: Marvel Heroic Roleplaying

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

There was a tag that was forgotten in the longer names update: [marvel-heroic](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marvel-heroic) for the Margared Weis Productions: Marvel Heroic Roleplaying. It should get its own tag updated/aliased to something more fitting. [marvel-heroic-roleplaying](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marvel-heroic-roleplaying) would be the official title, [mhrp](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mhrp) would be a valid shortcut that might be aliased in the process.

Comment: I would encourage you to mention that side note in the form of posting an answer to that Exalted meta question and accepting it. :)

Comment: @doppelgreener It was YOUR answer back there... - threw a comment

Comment: Oh! That works too. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Done: The tag has been renamed to [marvel-heroic-roleplaying](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marvel-heroic-roleplaying) to fit the name of the published game. Thanks for pointing this out!